# Assign variables past endlocal in a loop

Tags: batch-file

How do I preserve a number of variables (with a certain prefix) past `endlocal` in a loop?

Variables are visible in the loop declaration, but not body.

Here is an example with `echo` instead of variable assignment to illustrate that variables are not visible in the `for` body. Normally a variable assignment would go in place of the `echo`:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set TB_1=test1
set TB_2=test2

set TB_ALL_VARS=
for /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%x in ('set TB_') do (
  set TB_ALL_VARS=%%x !TB_ALL_VARS!
)

for %%x in (%TB_ALL_VARS%) do ( echo %%x = !%%x! ) 
echo END LOCAL
endlocal & ( for %%x in (%TB_ALL_VARS%) do ( echo %%x = !%%x! ) )
```

Output:

```
TB_2 = test2
TB_1 = test1
END LOCAL
TB_2 = !TB_2!
TB_1 = !TB_1!
```

As you can see, the variables are printed ok before endlocal, but not printed after endlocal.

Is there a way to save variables like this past endlocal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your example code, I think what you are asking is, "How do I set a dynamic number of variables after endlocal?"  What you ask is not terribly intuitive, but it *is* possible.  You can't use delayed expansion when compounding `set` with `endlocal`.  A workaround can often be employed to use a `for` loop to `endlocal & set "var=%%A"`, which only works if the number of variables and values are static.  Unfortunately, `endlocal & for` doesn't work the same as `for... in... do ( endlocal & set )`, as you've no doubt discovered in your own testing.

My solution is to use a macro to do the setting after `endlocal` -- basically putting *commands* rather than simple string values into a variable, then evaluating that variable as a set of `set` commands.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

:: // call ":set" subroutine to do the setting
call :set

:: // display results
set subv

:: // end main runtime
goto :EOF


:: // :set subroutine
:set
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: // any number of variables prefixed by "subv"
set "subv1=1"
set "subv2=2"
set "subv3=3"

:: // init %compound%
set compound=

:: // combine all %subvX% variables into a macro of set var1=val1 & set var2=val2, etc
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('set subv') do set "compound=!compound! & set "%%~I""

:: // evaluate set commands as a macro
endlocal & %compound:~3%
goto :EOF
```

---

Another solutions is to go back to the first workaround I mentioned, in the format of `endlocal & set "var=%%A"`.  Typically this is only used when you know you'll only loop once, something like

```js
for %%I in ("!var!") do endlocal & set "return=%%~I"
```

... because you don't want to endlocal too many times.  But you can do a multiple value loop with a single `endlocal` by employing `if not defined` like this:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

call :set
set subv

goto :EOF

:set
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "subv1=1"
set "subv2=2"
set "subv3=3"
set end=
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('set subv') do (
    if not defined end endlocal & set end=1
    set "%%~I"
)
goto :EOF
```

... and because `endlocal` and `set "%%~I"` are contained within a parenthetical code block, the variables are re-set and your goal is achieved.

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to use [tunneling](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=3712#p3712)  , but after endlocal you cannot use `!` to expand variables.Try this:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set TB_1=test1
set TB_2=test2

set TB_ALL_VARS=
for /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%x in ('set TB_') do (
  set TB_ALL_VARS=%%x !TB_ALL_VARS!
)

for %%x in (%TB_ALL_VARS%) do ( echo %%x = !%%x! ) 
echo END LOCAL
endlocal & ( for %%x in (%TB_ALL_VARS%) do ( call echo %%x = %%%%x%% ) )
```

OR

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set TB_1=test1
set TB_2=test2

set TB_ALL_VARS=
for /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%x in ('set TB_') do (
  set TB_ALL_VARS=%%x !TB_ALL_VARS!
)

for %%x in (%TB_ALL_VARS%) do ( echo %%x = !%%x! ) 
echo END LOCAL
endlocal & ( for %%x in (%TB_ALL_VARS%) do (
 setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
 call echo %%x = !%%x! )
 endlocal 
 )
```